# Cast ArrayList in Java

Tags: java

I am using two class

```
Class TestClassOne{
//Some methods
//Some methods
//Some methods
}

Class TestClassTwo extends TestClassOne{ 
//Some Variable
//Some Variable
//Some Variable
}
```

Now I am having TestClassOne object and can cast to TestClassTwo.

```
TestClassOne classOne = new TestClassOne();
TestClassTwo classTwo = (TestClassTwo)classOne;
```

Can I do this same for ArrayList?
For example

```
ArrayList<TestClassOne> testList1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<TestClassTwo> testList2 = (ArrayList<TestClassTwo>) testList1;
```

But I am getting error that can not cast. Is there any other way to cast the ArrayList?

Comment: `TestClassOne classOne = new TestClassOne();
TestClassTwo classTow = (TestClassTwo)abstractProfile` - are you meaning to cast `classOne`?

Comment: Yes. Now edited my question.

Comment: I am surpised you can do `TestClassTwo classTow = (TestClassTwo)classOne;`  Are you sure that `TestClassTow` doesn't extend `TestClassOne`?

Comment: How can you cast without inheritance?? I am surprised. Please provide code snippet in more details

Comment: Both the case you will get compilation error

Comment: I am really very sorry for the poor code post. Some Hurry burry I posted the code. Now I edited clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Generic types can't be converted to each other like that. `T<A>` cannot be casted to `T<B>` even though `B` inherits from `A`.

In this particular case, what you could do is cast each individual element in the array list, and use these to create a new array list.

```
ArrayList<TestClassTwo> testList2 = testList1.stream().map(x -> (TestClassTwo)x)
                                             .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))
```

Obviously, this will only work when the objects stored in the array list are all actually instances of `TestClassTwo`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple casting `TestClassOne-> TestClassTwo` will not work, unless your `testList1` collection holds instances of `TestClassTwo`, and only them.

Casting that you want to achieve is impossible, because even though `TestClassTwo` extends `TestClassOne`, there is no gurantee, that class `TestClassTwo` would have a suficient constructor. `TestClassTwo` may have additional variables, that JVM would not know what to do with. So as you can see this would be problematic even for  humans.

==========================================================================
Casting in other way is possible. Because `TestClassTwo` will have same methods as `TestClassOne`, because it extends it.

==========================================================================
If you want to hold elements of both `TestClassOne` and `TestClassTwo` in same collction, then you can use generic wildcards:

```
 List<? extends TestClassOne> testList1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

But you will have to check if given element is of type TestClassTwo, before casting.

```
TestClassOne one = testLis.get(1);
if(one instanceOf TestClassTwo.class) {
   (TestClassTwo) one; // handle me
}
   one; // can't be casted, but can be adapted
```

==========================================================================

Other solution would be to use an adapter constructor in `TestClassTwo`. It will accept `TestClassOne` as an argument (and optionaly insert additional parameters,  if needed). The creation of `TestClassTwo` objects should be managed by you.

```
class TestClassTwo extends TestClassOne{ 

     TestClassTwo(TestClassOne in) {...}
}
```

Then you can use simply adapt:

```
List<TestClassOne> testList1 = new ArrayList<>();//add some arguments
List<TestClassTwo> testList2 = testList1.stream().map(TestClassTwo::new).collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic class

```
class TestClassOne<T>
{

}
class TestClassTwo
{
}
```

Casting like this

```
List<TestClassOne<TestClassTwo>> list = new List<TestClassOne<TestClassTwo>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Inheritance with Type parameters are not supported.

Instead create a static helper method, which will iterate over one of the list, and cast each individual element, and return the new list. e.g.

```
    public static convert(ArrayList<ClassOne>) {
        ArrayList<ClassTwo> b = new ArrayList<ClassTwo>(); 
        forEach(classOne)  {
            b.add((ClassTwo)classOne);
        }
        return b;
    }
```